How to show the notification in Android using Kotlin without any permission?
In Android, we are attempting to send a notification without considering any permissions, yet still displaying the notification. I have used the following permissions:
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
Is there any method to send the notification without requiring these permissions in Android?
I am attempting to send a notification without the necessary notification permission. I have already tried utilising overlay and alarm notifications to send the notification without permission, but this approach did not work. Is there any other method to send the notification without relying on the notification permission in Android?

I'm not an android developer, but what would be the point of the permission if you can do that thing without needing the permission anyway?
